# heroku config vars to set emails for nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, heroku, nodemailer

I am on a nodejs app, using nodemailer to send emails.

I have set the `TO` emails in the heroku environment like the following:

```
TO_EMAILS
```

and the value is:

```
"['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com']"
```

however, when I receive the email, i get the email for the first one `email1@gmail.com` and nothing to the second one. However, the name of this first email appears as `['', 'email2@gmail.com']`

How can I set the variable so that I get the email sent to both email addresses?

### UPDATE:

I am following the nodemailer rules here: https://nodemailer.com/message/addresses/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to other syntax like:

```
TO_EMAILS=email1@gmail.com,email2@gmail.com
```

In you program get list email to send by way

```
var toEmails = process.env.TO_EMAILS.split(','); // toEmails is a array of strings
```